# SpringJUnit4ClassRunner plus Log4j2 plus log4j2.xml outside classpath

Tags: spring, log4j2

I have some tests that I run with `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner`. I also just migrated to Log4j2 and now I have trouble loading my `log4j2.xml` configuration file, I always get this error:

```
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default 
      configuration: logging only errors to the console.
```

The problem is that the configuration file is not on the classpath. Instead I keep it in a separate folder together with other configuration data outside of the classpath. When I start the test I already set `-Dconfig=/path/to/config/folder`. I know I can also pass `-Dlog4j.configurationFile=...` when I run the tests, but I do not want to do that.

What I want to do is use Spring annotation based configuration to write a configuration class in which I programatically set the location for Log4j. This is possible if I have a [web application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29995192/474034), but I don't know how to apply this to `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner`.

```
@Configuration
public class Log4jConfiguration {
    /** Initialize Log4j2 with a custom location for the log4j2.xml **/
}
```

Comment: By using `-Dlog4j.configurationFile=...` is exactly the same of what you are trying to achieve with `-Dconfig=/path/to/config/folder`. So, why not use the first option and rely on the **Automatic Configuration**? You don't really need to reinvent the wheel in this matter

Comment: Because I have other configuration files in that folder, and lots of places in my code are relying on this, so I don't want to change it.

Answer (score 0):

May be your Maven, specify:

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/java</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*.xml</include>
        </includes>
        <filtering>false</filtering>
    </resource>
    <resource>
        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*.properties</include>
            <include>**/*.xml</include><!---->
        </includes>
        <filtering>false</filtering>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

Check it.